# How to map Unicode codepoints from an UTF-16 file using C

Tags: c, unicode, utf-16

I need to read a file in binary mode which is written in UTF-16 encoding and transform it to UNICODE Codepoints. I had no problems to succesfully map the codepoints from the U+0000..U+FFFF interval. The problem is, from U+10000 to U+10FFFF UTF-16 encoding uses two pieces to form the Codepoint.

Example:  This rocket "  " is encoded in UTF-16 as 0xD83D 0xDE80, forming the UNICODE Codepoint: U+1F680.

Since UTF-16 encoding is exactly the same number as the UNICODE Codepoints from the interval U+0000 to U+FFFF, I wrote my code to simply translate the  UTF-16 reading into the UNICODE Codepoint. The problem is with U+10000 and forward, since my program understands the first piece (D83D) as being something from the interval U+0000 to U+FFFF.

How can I avoid this error? What can I do my code for it to know that the piece it's reading needs one more piece to successfully form the UNICODE Codepoint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is false: “UTF-16 encoding is exactly the same number as the UNICODE Codepoints from the interval U+0000 to U+FFFF”. UTF-16 0xD800 to 0xDFFF are [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF) which represent Unicode U+10000 on.

Answer (score 4):

The search term you are missing is "surrogate pair".  Note that the following code doesn't do any error checking or bounds checking.

```
int next_codepoint(uint16_t *text) {
    int c1 = text[0];
    if (c1 >= 0xd800 && c1 < 0xdc00) {
        int c2 = text[1];
        return ((c1 & 0x3ff) << 10) + (c2 & 0x3ff) + 0x10000;
    }
    return c1;
}
```

This is described in the Unicode specification which is freely available from the Unicode website, as well as Wikipedia articles on UTF-16.  There are also many libraries available for codec conversion, like iconv.  You are trying to convert UTF-16 to UTF-32, if that helps.

Comment: There is a mistake here the "+ 0x1000" should be "+ 0x10000".

Answer (score 0):

Either do the surrogate pair conversion, or use a library that does this for you, like iconv libunistring. See:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/
https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/

Example:

https://github.com/drichardson/examples/blob/master/iconv/utf8-to-utf32.c